# Apollo link state vs built-in React state

Tags: reactjs, state, apollo, apollo-link-state

I was thinking if I should use React built-in state `state = {}` when using apollo link state. Should I keep everything what is my local state in the apollo link state? Let me give you an example:

I have a `<Modal>` component which has a state:

```
state={visible: true}
```

Should be the above "state" kept in the apollo link state or React built-in state?

Comment: local for component, apollo for app/shared state - like redux

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on personal preference.

If the local state you want to save is related to the server state then i would use apollo
otherwise for something simple i would just use `setState`